# Can a master view controller be a delegate of a detail view controller?

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3

Is there any way to make a master view controller a delegate of a detail view controller in a master-detail template?

I have a segmented control in my detail view and I would like the user to be able to use it to determine which items should be shown in the master view.

I know how to do this without using master-detail template but cannot figure out how to do it with the template.

Comment: `detailVC.delegate = masterVC;` or I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: I cannot insert that line of code and hope to make anything work.

Comment: It seems the delegate property is set in AppDelegate.m so I am wondering whether it is possible to to set MasterViewController as delegate of DetailViewController

Comment: solved. H2CO3 was right